# How do I auto-hide placeholder text upon focus using css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome, placeholder

This is done automatically for every browser except Chrome.

I'm guessing I have to specifically target Chrome.

Any solutions?

If not with CSS, then with jQuery?

Comment: cehck my edit then, it might help

Comment: Opera is also another browser which removes placeholder on focus.

Comment: Firefox as of version 15 no longer removes the placeholder text until you start typing. I believe the same may be the case for IE10 but I don't have a way to verify that.

Comment: I am concerned that nobody mentioned the fact that you shouldn't  bother modifying native browser behaviors.  I for one prefer that the placeholder remains present.  It just helps me as an end user, and it's a feature that browsers are now starting to implement... probably because the disappear-on-focus behavior proved to be a usability problem. Let the browser be, please.

Comment: "This is done automatically for every browser except Chrome." Not anymore? I've just tried this on OSX in Firefox 37.0.2, Safari 7.1.5, and Chrome 42.0. None of them remove the placeholder text until I start typing, and all of them put it back when I clear the field.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

```
<input 
type="text" 
placeholder="enter your text" 
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" />
```

Comment: This makes it go but when I click away from the field it remains blank.

Comment: @LondonGuy: Just edited my post, see if it works like you wanted. But Toni Michel Caubet solution is nicer

Comment: The problem here is this is obtrusive JavaScript.  Toni Michel Caubet's solution is better.

Comment: I like it, but unfortunately it doesn't work neither IE nor Safari.

Comment: not working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jd2l6y-frudzk?file=app/table-filtering-example.html

Comment: Better to [never, ever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61900807) use inline handlers. They have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays.

Answer (score 621):

Edit:
All browsers support now

```css
input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something here!">
```

Firefox 15 and IE 10+ also supports this now. To expand on Casey Chu's CSS [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11920714/12892):

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
```

Comment: Great answer! I don't see much sense in abandoning my old jQuery solution in favor of HTML5 and then go right ahead and add the JavaScript back in as a fix. This is just the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @MartinHunt have you tried this on FF? input:focus::-moz-placeholder

Comment: Apologies for dredging up an old thread, but just to make this more complete: input:focus:-moz-placeholder is for Firefox 18 and below, for 19 onwards you need to use: input:focus::-moz-placeholder (note the double colon). Ref: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Comment: this comment is a win. works with dynamic controls, like kendo too

Comment: on printing in chrome doesn't work... any help
input[type=text].form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder, input[type=textarea].form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

Comment: Great answer also from me!
For those of us who might also require this functionality when the field is disabled here is the CSS code:

/* Hiding the placeholder text (if any), when the holding field is disabled */
input:disabled::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:disabled:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:disabled::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:disabled:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

Comment: `visibility: hidden` makes more sense to me. Using a transparent color is too hacky.

Answer (score 87):

Here is a CSS-only solution (for now, only works in WebKit):

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but the browser support for this just isn't there yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an elegant solution that frees you from logic.

Answer (score 64):

## Pure CSS Solution (no JS required)

Building on @Hexodus and @Casey Chu's answers, here is an updated and cross-browser solution that leverages CSS opacity and transitions to fade the placeholder text out.  It works for any element that can use placeholders, including `textarea` and `input` tags.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: opacity .5s; transition: opacity .5s; }  /* Chrome <=56, Safari < 10 */
:-moz-placeholder { opacity: 1; -moz-transition: opacity .5s; transition: opacity .5s; } /* FF 4-18 */
::-moz-placeholder { opacity: 1; -moz-transition: opacity .5s; transition: opacity .5s; } /* FF 19-51 */
:-ms-input-placeholder { opacity: 1; -ms-transition: opacity .5s; transition: opacity .5s; } /* IE 10+ */
::placeholder { opacity: 1; transition: opacity .5s; } /* Modern Browsers */
    
*:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { opacity: 0; } /* Chrome <=56, Safari < 10 */
*:focus:-moz-placeholder { opacity: 0; } /* FF 4-18 */
*:focus::-moz-placeholder { opacity: 0; } /* FF 19-50 */
*:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { opacity: 0; } /* IE 10+ */
*:focus::placeholder { opacity: 0; } /* Modern Browsers */
```

```html
<div>
  <div><label for="a">Input:</label></div>
  <input id="a" type="text" placeholder="CSS native fade out this placeholder text on click/focus" size="60">
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <div><label for="b">Textarea:</label></div>
  <textarea id="b" placeholder="CSS native fade out this placeholder text on click/focus" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

#### Revisions

- *Edit 1 (2017): Updated to support modern browsers.*
- *Edit 2 (2020): Added the runnable Stack Snippet.*

Comment: The best CSS solution!

Comment: Good old CSS... great simple solution! Why didn't I think of that??

Answer (score 42):

have you tried placeholder attr?

```
<input id ="myID" type="text" placeholder="enter your text " />
```

-EDIT-

I see, try this then:

```
$(function () {

    $('#myId').data('holder', $('#myId').attr('placeholder'));

    $('#myId').focusin(function () {
        $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
    });
    $('#myId').focusout(function () {
        $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('holder'));
    });


});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/mPLFf/4/

-EDIT-

Actually, since placeholder should be used to describe the value, not the name of the input. I suggest the following alternative

**html:**

```
<label class="overlabel"> 
    <span>First Name</span>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
</label>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('.overlabel').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var field = $this.find('[type=text], [type=file], [type=email], [type=password], textarea');
    var span = $(this).find('> span');
    var onBlur = function () {
        if ($.trim(field.val()) == '') {
            field.val('');
            span.fadeIn(100);
        } else {
            span.fadeTo(100, 0);
        }
    };
    field.focus(function () {
        span.fadeOut(100);
    }).blur(onBlur);
    onBlur();
});
```

**css:**

```
.overlabel {
  border: 0.1em solid;
  color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 2.2em;
}
.overlabel span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.overlabel span, .overlabel input {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* prevent ios styling */
  border-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Test:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwynwrcf/

Comment: Nice to see the data attribute being used. But I would look at the CSS equivalent. When cached it will be a faster solution and can be global. The above needs the data attribute to be placed on every element needed. (answer below)

Comment: This is overcomplicated. Could be done with far less code.

Comment: @JGallardo show me the light ( but i'm not sure if you have seen that there are 3 different solutions )

Answer (score 19):

To augment @casey-chu's and pirate rob's answer, here's a more cross browser compatible way:

```
    /* WebKit browsers */
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

    /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }

    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }

    /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
```

Comment: Exactly what i have written now (instead i used `opacity:0;`)! The only CSS solution in this thread with all possible browser supports!

Answer (score 12):

Toni's answer is good, but I'd rather drop the `ID` and explicitly use `input`, that way all inputs with `placeholder` get the behavior:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your text" />
```

Note that `$(function(){ });` is the shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ });`:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').data('holder',$('input').attr('placeholder'));
    $('input').focusin(function(){
        $(this).attr('placeholder','');
    });
    $('input').focusout(function(){
        $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('holder'));
    });
})
```

**[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/6CzRq/5/)**

Comment: This doesn't work if you have more than one field. Here is enhanced version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/6CzRq/64/

Answer (score 9):

I like to package this up in the name space and run on elements with the "placeholder" attribute...

```
$("[placeholder]").togglePlaceholder();

$.fn.togglePlaceholder = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this)
        .data("holder", $(this).attr("placeholder"))
        .focusin(function(){
            $(this).attr('placeholder','');
        })
        .focusout(function(){
            $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('holder'));
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you need *SPECIFICITY* to make sure your styles are applied with strongest factor `id` Thanks for @Rob Fletcher for his great answer, in our company we have used

So please consider adding styles prefixed with the id of the app container

```css
    #app input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, #app  textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    #app input:focus:-moz-placeholder, #app textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

With Pure CSS it worked for me. Make it transparent when Entered/Focues in input

```
 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: transparent !important;
 }
 input:focus::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: transparent !important;
 }
 input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
   color: transparent !important;
 }
 input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: transparent !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Angular any version

Just add this to your .css file

```
.hide_placeholder:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

and use in your input in class

```
<input class="hide_placeholder"
```

Answer (score 4):

To further refine [Wallace Sidhrée](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909777/wallace-sidhree)'s code sample:

```
$(function()
{  
      $('input').focusin(function()
      {
        input = $(this);
        input.data('place-holder-text', input.attr('placeholder'))
        input.attr('placeholder', '');
      });

      $('input').focusout(function()
      {
          input = $(this);
          input.attr('placeholder', input.data('place-holder-text'));
      });
})
```

This ensures that each input stores the correct placeholder text in the data attribute.

See a [working example here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/truetone/sHYz3/3/).

Answer (score 4):

I like the css approach spiced with transitions. On Focus the placeholder fades out ;) Works also for textareas.

Thanks @Casey Chu for the great idea.

```css
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder, input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; 
}

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  { 
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a pure CSS based solution:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  {color:transparent;}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder   {color:transparent;}
input:-moz-placeholder   {color:transparent;}
```

**Note:** 
Not yet supported by all browser vendors.

Reference: [Hide placeholder text on focus with CSS](http://www.toolinfy.com/hide-placeholder-text-on-focus-css) by Ilia Raiskin.

Answer (score 4):

Using SCSS along with http://bourbon.io/, this solution is simple, elegant, and works on all web browsers:

```
input:focus {
  @include placeholder() {
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Use Bourbon ! It's good for you !

Answer (score 3):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter your text" id="myInput" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#myInput').focus(function(){
  $(this).attr('placeholder','');
});
$('#myInput').focusout(function(){
  $(this).attr('placeholder','enter your text');
});
```

Comment: This only assumes one input.

Answer (score 3):

This piece of CSS worked for me:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color:transparent;

}
```

Comment: That's A nice way of doing it without JQuery :)

Answer (score 3):

**2018 > JQUERY v.3.3 SOLUTION:**
Working globaly for all input, textarea with placeholder.

```
 $(function(){
     $('input, textarea').on('focus', function(){
        if($(this).attr('placeholder')){
           window.oldph = $(this).attr('placeholder');
            $(this).attr('placeholder', ' ');
        };
     });

     $('input, textarea').on('blur', function(){
       if($(this).attr('placeholder')){
            $(this).attr('placeholder', window.oldph);
         };
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If your input background color is white, then you can set the placeholder text color on focus to match the input background - making the text invisible; theoretically. If you're input is a different color, then just simply change the color to match it.

```
input:focus::placeholder {
  color: white;
}
```

Also, you can set the color to "transparent" shown in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Demo is here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/5MG8b/3/)**

Try this :

```
//auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus
if(!$.browser.webkit){
$("input").each(
        function(){
            $(this).data('holder',$(this).attr('placeholder'));
            $(this).focusin(function(){
                $(this).attr('placeholder','');
            });
            $(this).focusout(function(){
                $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('holder'));
            });

        });

}
```

Comment: use $("input[placeholder]") instead to only select fields that have a placeholder attribute.

Comment: This is the best answer, simple, and deselects the others when out of focus

Answer (score 1):

for input

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
```

for textarea

```
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[placeholder]").focusin(function () {
    $(this).data('place-holder-text', $(this).attr('placeholder')).attr('placeholder', '');
})
.focusout(function () {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('place-holder-text'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-placeholder", this.placeholder);

    $(this).bind("focus", function () {
        this.placeholder = '';
    });
    $(this).bind("blur", function () {
        this.placeholder = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides all of above,I have two ideas.

You can add an element that imitates the palceholder.Then using javascript control the element showing and hiding.

But it is so complex,the other one is using the brother's selector of css.Just like this:

```html
.placeholder { position: absolute; font-size: 14px; left: 40px; top: 11px; line-height: 1; pointer-events: none; }
.send-message input:focus + .placeholder { display: none; }
```

23333,I have a poor English.Hope solve your problem.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up ;

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any CSS or JQuery. You can do it right from the HTML input tag.

**For example**, In below email box, the placeholder text will disappear after clicking inside and the text will appear again if clicked outside.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Type your email here..." onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Type your email here...'">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function:

+It Hides The PlaceHolder On Focus And Returns It Back On Blur

+This function depends on the placeholder selector, first it selects the elements with the placeholder attribute, triggers a function on focusing and another one on blurring.

on focus : it adds an attribute "data-text" to the element which gets its value from the placeholder attribute then it removes the value of the placeholder attribute.

on blur : it returns back the placeholder value and removes it from the data-text attribute

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
```

```js
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-text', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
  }).blur(function() {
      $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).attr('data-text'));
      $(this).attr('data-text', '');
  });
});
```

you can follow me very well if you look what's happening behind the scenes by inspecting the input element

Answer (score 0):

The same thing i have applied in angular 5.

i created a new string for storing placeholder

```
newPlaceholder:string;
```

then i have used focus and blur functions on input box(i am using prime ng autocomplete).

Above placeholder is being set from typescript

Two functions i am using -

```
/* Event fired on focus to textbox*/
Focus(data) {
    this.newPlaceholder = data.target.placeholder;
    this.placeholder = '';
}
/* Event fired on mouse out*/
Blur(data) {
    this.placeholder = this.newPlaceholder;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Webkit */
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { opacity: 0; }
/* Firefox < 19 */
[placeholder]:focus:-moz-placeholder { opacity: 0; }
/* Firefox > 19 */
[placeholder]:focus::-moz-placeholder { opacity: 0; }
/* Internet Explorer 10 */
[placeholder]:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { opacity: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer is identical to a previous answer. If you have something to add or improve, please suggest an edit to the original answer.