# Clear input search text on click is not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

Why this basic script its not working? I already used this other times and it works and now its not working.

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." required="required" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search...') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Search...'}" /> 
  <button type="submit"><img src="search-icon-2.png" /></button>
</form>
```

Comment: remove placeholder tag and it works fine

Comment: You are changing the value of the input, but you have a `placeholder` attribute. Either use your script, or use the `placeholder` tag. Either will work the same way, the caveat is merely a browser support issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for and changing the `value` property when you should be changing the `placeholder` property:

```
 <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." required="required" onfocus="if(this.placeholder == 'Search...') {this.placeholder=''}" onblur="if(this.placeholder == ''){this.placeholder ='Search...'}" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you want a CSS-based solution for this problem, you can add these following rules in your CSS file:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
```

Refer to this answer for other options: [How do I auto-hide placeholder text upon focus using css or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707021/how-do-i-auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus-using-css-or-jquery)

Comment: Thank you, I have the habit to use the value so I even noticed I was doing wrong.

Comment: This answer is completely redundant to what the `placeholder` attribute is already doing.

Comment: Why would you remove the placeholder … it has it already “build-in” _by definition_ that it doesn’t get displayed any more once the user starts typing or the field is not empty any more …

Comment: No, in some browsers the placeholder text won't clear when you focus on the textbox. That is what the OP wants.

Comment: No, in some browsers the `placeholder` doesn't work *period*: http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Comment: I don't think you understood the OP's problem here. He wants the placeholder text to be cleared on focus, not when the user starts typing which is the default behavior of the `placeholder` attribute in Chrome and Firefox. I am not talking about browsers that don't support the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **onfocus** and **onblur** as I tested and it worked fine on chrome browser. It was written in gray (as a hint text not ordinary text).