# Placeholder doesn't disappear when input field in focus

Tags: html, css

The placeholder value of each input field on a form should disappear when the user selects the field, but it does not. Doctype is HTML5.

http://dailyspiro.com/index.html

```
<input required type="text" name="user-first-name" id="user-first-name" placeholder="First Name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all decorative-icon icon-user" />
```

Comment: What browser/OS are you on? No problems here on OSX 10.9.2 with Safari  7.0.2.

Comment: no problem here either

Comment: Also, it shouldn't 
"disappear" until you type -

Comment: http://sridharkatakam.com/make-search-form-input-box-text-go-away-focus-genesis/ the normal behavior is for the text go away when you start typing, not click. any number of JS/CSS tricks can add the ability to disappear on focus.

Comment: The `placeholder` will display as long as the `value` is empty, not just on focus. Type something into the field and it should hide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-hide placeholder text upon focus using css or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707021/how-do-i-auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus-using-css-or-jquery)

Answer (score 9):

**CSS**

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 18- */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* oldIE ;) */
```

see here http://sridharkatakam.com/make-search-form-input-box-text-go-away-focus-genesis/

Comment: Ahh. Sorry! Kinda duped your answer from that article. Good read nonetheless!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same thing with a little js. Not sure if you're looking or a plain HTML. @chiliNUT's option should work for you. Anyway, since I'm not *totally* clear on what you want...

Here are 2 options:

```
<input required type="text" name="user-first-name" id="user-first-name" class="your list of class names" placeholder="First Name" onfocus="if(this.value == 'First Name') { this.value = ''; }" value="First Name"/>

<input required type="text" name="user-first-name" id="user-first-name" class="your list of class names" onfocus="if(this.value == 'First Name') { this.value = ''; }" value="First Name"/>
```

And the [obligatory fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J84Sb/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onfocus` and `onblur` events directly into the HTML input tag

```html
<input onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'click me'" placeholder="click me"/>
```

For more info and examples [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no-one's mentioned the simplest way to do this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Your Name'"
```

The `onblur` is only necessary if you want to restore the original placeholder after the user clicks away from the input.