# How to make disappear the place holder without using JS/jQuery?

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

In my search field I just figured it out that, when I click the `input` field it remains till the content entered. I want to hide the placeholder when the field is clicked.

Since this site is going to be delivered to another team I don't want to add JavaScript or jQuery code here. Because it was one of the requirement from the client. How can achieve it using CSS and HTML? This is a default behavior of HTML.

`<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Keywords or Chassis/ Reference No">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder doesn't disappear when input field in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431297/placeholder-doesnt-disappear-when-input-field-in-focus)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the selector `input:focus::placeholder`:

```css
input:focus::placeholder {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Keywords or Chassis/ Reference No">
```