# Remove Place Holder from a text box in Mobile device

Tags: html, css, input, responsive-design, placeholder

I have **textbox** in my page and which has a placeholder. I need to remove the place holder from that **textbox** in mobile devices. The **textbox** has a class `.search-box`.

Comment: Are you using any kind of javascript or server side programming language? This could help to find a solution.

Comment: Why is the placeholder not useful on a mobile device?

Answer (score 3):

First, get the current viewport width and compare it to your mobile version's max width.

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
```

Then, you can use jQuery **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to change the value of your placeholder if the viewport width is less than the mobile version's max width, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    if(w < 657){ // or replace with your mobile version's max width
      $(".search-box").attr("placeholder", "");
    }
});
```

and on window resize:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
     var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
     if(w < 657){ // or replace with your mobile version's max width
        $(".search-box").attr("placeholder", "");
     }
     else{
        $(".search-box").attr("placeholder", "Im a placeholder");
    }
});
```

**[Here's a demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ct3ngtxw/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Only CSS (*only for modern browsers*):

@JamesKing approach was good but he mentioned non-existing selectors. Here is the modified approach:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {  /* mention the width limit here */
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color:transparent;
    }
    input:-moz-placeholder {
        color:transparent;
    }
    input::-moz-placeholder {
        color:transparent;
    }
}
```

As explained by [DavidWalsh](http://davidwalsh.name/placeholder-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a mobile device using javascript as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/743016. Note that this does not guarantee that it will work on any mobile device!

In this code you can remove the placeholder with jquery.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $("textarea").removeAttr("placeholder");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It feels hacky but you can hide it using CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .search-box::placeholder {
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is `::placeholder`. can you provide source? I saw [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12250084/1577396) which is using vendor prefixes.