# Twitter Bootstrap tags input doesn't remove placeholder when onfocus

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have been scratching my head since yesterday on this problem, which I cannot solve. I am a new starter to Twitter Bootstrap and everything was going well until yesterday.

I am using the latest JQuery v1.11.1 and Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.1. Yesterday I downloaded Bootstrap Tags Input, from here: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

The plugin works and I have changed the CSS styles to match my page layout but the problem I am having is that the placeholder attribute will not disappear when on focus. If I type in a tag and add a comma value the placeholder will show until I start typing and then it will disappear again.

I have tried using JQuery onfocus function to remove the attribute when onfocus but it doesn't do anything. What I want to achieve is that when onfocus the placeholder does not show at that point not even on blur.

My input field is demonstrated below:

`<input type="text" name="customer_tags" id="customer_tags" value="" placeholder="Enter you tags" data-role="tagsinput" required />`

Comment: Which browser do  you see this behaviour in?

Comment: can you give a link or jsbin/codepen etc? "show until I start typing" sounds like its acting as it should.

Comment: Hi it is Firefox 34.0.5 which is the latest version

Comment: @atmd here is the link to my code http://brightlet.kollkolen.com/tagsinput.html as you can see when typing a comma the placeholder shows again.

Comment: if you don't want complete tag input when you press comma , you should try to remove something on your plug-in, maybe only 'confirmKeys: [13]'.
"Comma" is confirm for your input which completed.

Comment: @haxtbh here is the link to my code: http://brightlet.kollkolen.com/tagsinput.html

Comment: This is hard to fix. You can try the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707021/how-do-i-auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus-using-css-or-jquery but when the focus is out the placeholder will return. Since bootstrap cleans the input value to create the tags you need to save state in javascript or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

two years later, but i found how to work around this issue.  First, if you inspect the DOM , you will see a new input text, which inherits our placeholder text, but without the extra function onblur, onfocus that everybody mention before.

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
<input placeholder="text inherited from our input" size="23" type="text">
</div>
```

Then, to fix this issue, you had to create a jquery function to point that input.  Like this:

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').blur(function(){jQuery(this).attr('placeholder', '')})
```

pointing to element with the class "bootstrap-tagsinput" and then the "input" objects inside.  You can add a .focus function too if you prefered.  In my case, works when the user leave the object and the input tags look clean without placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 `placeholder` attribute will not disappear when you focus in the `input` tag... it will only disappear when you start typing. It is the default behavior.

You can see it @ [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) as well...

Comment: I'd suggest the MDN docs on inputs (including placeholders) rather then w3schools https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply and I understand this but the behavior is not the same. The placeholder will show after a comma until you start typing again. I will arrange a link to my code just bare with me

Answer (score 1):

Following code works in my case:

```
    <input type="text" name="add_image_tags" id="add_image_tags" data-role="tagsinput" 
class="form-control" placeholder="Enter tags" data-placeholder="Enter tags" value="" />

handlePlaceHolder(); //Call during page load

function handlePlaceHolder()
{    
    if($('#add_image_tags').val())
    {
        $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').attr('placeholder', '');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').attr('placeholder',$('#add_image_tags').attr('data-placeholder'));
    }
}

$('#add_image_tags').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
  // event.item: contains the item
  handlePlaceHolder();
});

$('#add_image_tags').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  // event.item: contains the item
  handlePlaceHolder();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope it's working:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="name" class="left-label">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="example-two" placeholder="Enter you tags" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease; 
  opacity: 0;
}

.example-two:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: text-indent 0.5s 0.5s ease; 
  text-indent: -100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

body {

}
form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font: bold 0.8em Sans-Serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.left-label {
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 5px 0 0;
}
input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
  text-indent: 0;
}
form div {
  margin: 20px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLs1vto9/)

EDIT:
Working on IE too:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLs1vto9/2/)

Comment: Hi @Joci93 here is the link to my code http://brightlet.kollkolen.com/tagsinput.html as you can see when typing a comma the placeholder shows again.

Comment: @Cam
Try:

<input type="text" placeholder="enter your text" size="31" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" style="width: 31em !important;">

   little bugy, but working

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. Try adding data-role="tagsinput" attribute in the input as it needs to work with Bootstrap Tags Input plugin

Comment: Maybe:
<input type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '" enter="" you="" preferred="" local="" placeholder="" data-role="tagsinput" style="width: 31em !important;" size="31">

Comment: sorry it doesn't work and it does look very messy. I like clean code if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

That's how the plugin behaves. As soon as you hit "enter" or "comma" it creates a span tag (see image attached)and shift the input to the right. So now the input has no value and should show the placeholder.

[image]

[In their docs it's mentioned](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) [Search for confirmKeys]

> Array of keycodes which will add a tag when typing in the input.
>   (default: [13, 188], which are ENTER and comma)

Change the confirmkeys to remove creation of tags when you type `comma`

**Edit:**

On your [site](http://brightlet.kollkolen.com/tagsinput.html) I tried the below method in console and it worked.

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [13]
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I have tried this but even after typing a comma it still does the same :(

Comment: On your site, in the console I tried this `$('input').tagsinput({confirmKeys: [13]});` in console and it worked. Are you sure you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a quick fix using jquery. The behavior I wanted should do two things:

1) Remove placeholder while on page after I've focused and started typing. So I will run it on keyup.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.bootstrap-tagsinput input', function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '')
})
```

2) If there are already labels in an input, then I don't obviously need a placeholder. I run this on page load.

```
$('.labels').each(function(){
    var len = $(this).tagsinput('items');
    if(len){
        var $input = $($(this).prev().children('input').get(0));
        $input.attr('placeholder', '');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after a little modification, it works fine.

```
$('#txtTimeSlot').on('change', function () {
        var len = $(this).tagsinput('items').length;
        if (len > 0) {

            var $input = $($(this).prev().children('input').get(0));
            $input.attr('placeholder', '');
        } else {

            var $input = $($(this).prev().children('input').get(0));
            $input.attr('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for all who are still having this problem, just change the line in the javascript file:

from:

```
cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty: true,
```

to

```
cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty: false,
```

And thats all!