# How to hide placeholder on a button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input text field with placeholder and its value as shown below:

```
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="testing">
```

and I have two buttons, one is used to hide and another one is used to show the placeholder:

```
<button id="btn-hide">Hide</button>
<button id="btn-show">Show</button>
```

I want to hide the placeholder when I click on the button hide and show the placeholder when I click on the button show.I have googled and I come to know that it is possible to do by using css, but I still can not find any solution. Can anyone help me either using jquery or css or whatever? Thank you so much for answering my question.

Comment: Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qgqxLo7u/

Comment: //Already have solutions: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707021/how-do-i-auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus-using-css-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't jQuery solution. Save your placeholder in a global var so you can reset it.

```js
var placeholder = $('#txtInput').attr('placeholder');

$('#btn-hide').on('click', function() {
 $('#txtInput').attr('placeholder' ,'');
});

$('#btn-show').on('click', function() {
 $('#txtInput').attr('placeholder' ,placeholder);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" type="text" name="test" placeholder="testing">
<button id="btn-hide">Hide</button>
<button id="btn-show">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is pure css. It targets all input fields and onFocus it makes the font color transparent.

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
```

Comment: Some explanation about your code would improve your answer drastically.

Comment: The solution is pure css. It targets all input fields and onFocus it makes the font color transparent.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove and add attrbiute with jquery

```
$('#btn-hide').on('click', function(){

    $('input[name="test"]').removeAttr("placeholder")
})

$('#btn-show').on('click', function(){

    $('input[name="test"]').attr("placeholder", 'text')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help you?

```
$("#btn-hide").click(function(){
   $("input[name='test']").attr("placeholder"," ");
});
$("#btn-show").click(function(){
   $("input[name='test']").attr("placeholder","testing");
});
```

**P.S**: It's not tested

Answer (score 0):

Jquery :

```
$('#btn-hide').click(function(){
  $('input').removeAttr('placeholder');
})

$('#btn-show').click(function(){
  $('input').attr('placeholder','testing');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery just use this code

```
 $("#btn-hide").click(function () {
        $("[name=test]").removeAttr("placeholder");
  });

  $("#btn-show").click(function () {
        $("[name=test]").attr("placeholder","testing");
  });
```

Comment: $("test") won't select any thing

Comment: $('input[name="test"]') you can use it also if it's also not work then give id of your textbox like id="txt" then $("#txt") it's work

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jquery/javascript function to show or hide your controls.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="testing"/>
<button id="btn-hide" click="hide_text()">Hide</button>
<button id="btn-show" click="show_text()">Show</button>
```

jQuery:

```
function hide_text(){
   $('input[placeholder:testing]').hide();
}

function show_text(){
   $('input[placeholder:testing]').show();
}
```

.show and .hide are jQuery function that will set the display of the indicated control.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need separate buttons for hide and show. You could have a single button that toggles placeholder and the button text is changed accordingly. https://jsfiddle.net/x337ey8p/2/

**JS** (pure)

```
function togglePlaceholder(btn) {
    var tb = document.getElementById('test1');

    if (tb.placeholder != '') {
       tb.placeholder = '';
       btn.innerHTML = 'Show';
    }
    else {
      tb.placeholder = 'testing';
      btn.innerHTML = 'Hide';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="test1" type="text" name="test" placeholder="testing">
<button id="btn-show" onclick="togglePlaceholder(this)">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a pure javascript way to achieve the same.
**JS**(pure)

HTML

```
<input id="inputId" type="text" name="test" placeholder="testing">
<button id="btn-hide" onclick ='hidePlaceholder()'>Hide</button>
<button id="btn-show" onclick ='showPlaceholder()'>Show</button>
```

JS

```
var placeholderVal;
function hidePlaceholder(){
     placeholderVal = document.getElementById("inputId").placeholder;
     document.getElementById("inputId").placeholder = "";
}
function showPlaceholder(){
     document.getElementById("inputId").placeholder = placeholderVal;
}
```

This is how you can show/hide placeholder of an input using javaScript only.
Thanks!