# How to remove placeholder text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have written some code to remove the input placeholder text and it works as expected. The problem I have is how do I reset the value of placeholder after it has been removed?

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

if (input.placeholder) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
    input.placeholder = '';
  });
} else {
  input.placeholder.preventDefault()
};
```

```html
<div class="mainInput">
  <input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Enter your todo : ">
  <button class="btn" id="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<span> Todo list : </span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? Why do you remove the placeholder in the first place?

Comment: use remove attribute function on load : input.removeAttribute("placeholder");

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes there is no need to remove the placeholder.

Comment: By default any placeholder text is removed as soon as you start typing in the input - when you clear the input it is "reset" (placeholder text reappears). I am really not sure what you are trying to achieve here beyond the default behaviour

Comment: if you just want to hide the placeholder then this is the solution you are looking for

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707021/how-do-i-auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus-using-css-or-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should work for you!

It will just reset your placeholder value.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

if (input) {
   // it will remove placeholder value on focus and store with dataset variable
  input.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
    input.dataset.placeholder = input.placeholder
    input.placeholder = '';
  });
    
  // it will reset placeholder value on blur by dataset variable
  input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    input.placeholder = input.dataset.placeholder;
  });
}else{
  console.log("input is not defined",input);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainInput">
  <input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Enter your todo : ">
  <button class="btn" id="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<span> Todo list : </span>
```