# Adding the greyish text in the credential fields using HTML

Tags: html

Some websites have a greyish text written in the blanks next to the credentials required, for exampl [Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrjyC.png) (I'm not allowed to add pictures, sadly), however, when you click in the box, the greyish text disappears. I have the following code in HTML but I don't know whether it's possible to add that feature or not:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My code</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Registration form</h1>

        <form>
            <fieldset>
                
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label> 
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email"><br><br>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, the boxes/fields appear empty and don't show the greyish text (like 'Email'). Can anyone tell me how to add that feature using HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` attribute.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello">
```

Note:
You can change the styles of the placeholder using css `::placeholder` pseudo element.

Edit:
If you want to hide the placeholder when focused do this:

```css
#myInput:focus::placeholder{
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello" id="myInput">
```

Comment: Bravo!! Thanks! (One additional question if you don't mind: this worked but when I clicked the box, the greyish text was still there and only disappeared when I typed in there, unlike the one in Google, do you know how to do that?)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not in a hurry, do it at your convenience :)

Comment: Your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707021/how-do-i-auto-hide-placeholder-text-upon-focus-using-css-or-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the attribute called `placeholder` in html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My code</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Registration form</h1>

        <form>
            <fieldset>
                
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"><br><br>
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label> 
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the puzzle. (Sorry. I don't have enough reputation to upvote)