# AS3 - Placeholder text within textbox components

Tags: flash, actionscript, textfield, placeholder

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to what is required at this link-

[Text in HTML Field to disappear when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626107/text-in-html-field-to-disappear-when-clicked)

This is for Flash using actionscript 3, originally I just had the textboxes with default text to indentify them but having the placeholder would be a nice addition.

I thought of possibly just having the text added in by default, and on focus disappearing, but if anyone knows of a simpler solution I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no more straight forward / automated solution.

Alternatively, you could keep the placeholder text until the user actually typed something, using TextField [TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event%3atextInput) event , and only move the cursor a the beginning of the text on focus using

```
TextField.setSelection(0,0);
```