# Clear textarea containing instructions on click or when text is entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript, so I'm not sure where to look to do this.

I have a web page where the user can enter a message in a textarea box. I want to have instructions for them in the box, this is just an example:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" ROWS=10 COLS=80>Enter your text here</TEXTAREA>
```

When the user clicks within this textarea boxes or starting to enter text, I want it to immediately clear out the instructions text.

I've seen this done on web pages, but I can't find any to examine.

Comment: Use the `placeholder` attribute of the `<textarea>`.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626107/text-in-html-field-to-disappear-when-clicked/5077265#5077265

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text in HTML Field to disappear when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626107/text-in-html-field-to-disappear-when-clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just replace it with a `placeholder`.

```html
<textarea name="message" rows=10 cols=80 placeholder="Enter your text here"></textarea>
```

or you could do this by `binding` event handlers for `blur` and `focus`.

```js
let message="Enter your text here";
$('textarea').focus(function(){
  if($(this).val() === message)
       $(this).val('');
});
$('textarea').blur(function(){
  if($(this).val().length === 0)
       $(this).val(message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="message" rows=10 cols=80>Enter your text here</textarea>
```

Comment: When the user clicks on it, it does nothing. I want it to clear the text on click too, not just when they enter text.

Comment: @EdwardCoast, have a look now.

Comment: Does it matter where in the web page this JavaScript is placed? I already have an onclick button that calls a function. Is this event like clicking on a button so I could place it anywhere?

Comment: You should also use `click` function.

Comment: In this example `click` is also suitable instead of `focus` in order to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

use placeholder to do this

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" ROWS=10 COLS=80 placeholder="Enter your text here"></TEXTAREA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want to use javascript or jquery then try the below code

```js
     $(function() {
    var defaultText = 'Enter your text here';
    $('#txt').focus(function() {
        defaultText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val().length === 0)
        $(this).val(defaultText); 
        
     });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" id="txt" ROWS=10 COLS=80 >Enter your text here</TEXTAREA>
```

Comment: This is probably undesirable, because if the user enters some text, leaves the control, and then reenters the control, it will delete what they entered.

Comment: Also add event handler for `blur` method in order to reinitialize the value.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an **event on focus** to your text area.

```
//assigns value to yext area

    document.getElementById("textarea").value = "this is an example";

    //does focus event
        document.getElementById("textarea").addEventListener("focus", myFocusMethod, true) ;

        function myFocusMethod(){
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = "";
        }

    //does click
    function doClick() {
    }

<TEXTAREA id="textarea" NAME="message" ROWS=10 COLS=80 onclick="doClick();"></TEXTAREA>
```

Comment: Where in the flow of a web page does this get put in the JavaScript? I have a clickon button which calls a function. Would this be part of that function?

Comment: before the function.  this even listenes to the client actions and acts when a client focuses on the text area. updated snippet with comments for you.